# How to generate local notification at the end of the incoming call in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications, call, core-telephony

I want to know how to generate local notification at the end of the incoming call in Iphone using core telephony frame work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't intercept every phone call, unless your app is an app that is allowed to run in th background. Like VOIP, navigation (or other GRPS tracker) or playing audio.

You can use the apple example to see if there is a call active and set the `callEventHandler` block.
Then check if there the is ended by checkin if the `callState` is equal to `CTCallStateDisconnected`.